# How to push (Arrow Function) into array?

Tags: php

I am trying to insert code (double Arrow) into an array.  But no matter how I try, I can't get it to work. My actual attempt is to push the new code to the variable but I'm getting this error:

> "syntax error, unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW)"

What is the right way to add code to that array?

```
    $shortcode[] = 'attendee_name' => $tickets[0]['shortcode_data']['attendee_name'];
    
    $shortcode = array(
        'product_name'  => $tickets[0]['shortcode_data']['product_name'],
        'start_time'    => $tickets[0]['shortcode_data']['start_time'],
        'end_time'      => $tickets[0]['shortcode_data']['end_time'],
    );
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you probably want to just assign to a key:

```
$shortcode = array(...);

$shortcode['attendee_name'] =  $tickets[0]['shortcode_data']['attendee_name'];
```

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way would be to just assign

```
$shortcode = $tickets[0]['shortcode_data'];
```

`print_r($shortcode)` would then output:

```
Array
(
    [attendee_name] => 12
    [product_name] => 12
    [start_time] => 12
    [end_time] => 12
)
```